# In Stata: how to evaluate a string stored in a macro as a variable name?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

In a Stata program, I'm trying to get a variable name, modify it using `regexr(oldvarname, "some_regex", "replacement")`, store it in a new local `local newvarname`, and use that modified variable name in a `` replace othervar = 1 if `newvarname' == 1 `` statement. Below is a minimal example of what I would like to achieve.

```
program define testprog
  syntax varlist
 

  foreach var of varlist `varlist' {
    local bin_check regexm("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$")

    if `bin_check' {
        local varfreq regexr("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$", "freq")
    }
    else {
        local varfreq `var'freq
    }
    
    gen `var'_wk = .
    replace `var'_wk = 1 if `varfreq' == 1
  }
end

gen joboffers_earn = 0
gen joboffers_earnbinbot = 0
gen joboffers_earnfreq = 1

testprog joboffers_earn joboffers_earnbinbot
```

In this example, `varfreq` is interpreted correctly for the first variable (which involves appending "freq" to the end of the variable), but not the second variable (which involves a slightly more complex replacing of substrings in the variable name).

In short, how do I get Stata to evaluate the result of `regexr()` as a variable name instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the macro assignment: for the expression to be evaluated, it has to be assigned using the `=` operator. Without it, the content of the macro is stored as a literal string.

Thus, `` local varfreq regexr("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$", "freq") `` needs to be changed to `` local varfreq = regexr("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$", "freq") ``.

The fully working code becomes:

```
program define testprog
  syntax varlist
 

  foreach var of varlist `varlist' {
    local bin_check regexm("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$")

    if `bin_check' {
        local varfreq = regexr("`var'", "bin(bot|mid|top)$", "freq")
    }
    else {
        local varfreq `var'freq
    }
    
    gen `var'_wk = .
    replace `var'_wk = 1 if `varfreq' == 1
  }
end

gen joboffers_earn = 0
gen joboffers_earnbinbot = 0
gen joboffers_earnfreq = 1

testprog joboffers_earn joboffers_earnbinbot
```

H/T to Clyde for his answer on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1747690-how-to-evaluate-a-string-stored-in-a-macro-as-a-variable-name?p=1747695#post1747695).